# How to remove folder name with htaccess in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

So, I already put my website in hosting web server.
I have one problem right now.

for example I have this URL for my site :

```
http://www.example.com/norwin/beranda
```

I want to remove or delete the folder name `'norwin'` from the URL

I am placing my htaccess file in `public_html/norwin/.htaccess`

this is my `.htaccess` code :

```
RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|stylesheets|system/application/sources/)

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/norwin/$1 [NC,L]
```

this rules is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing your routes.php

```
$route['controller/function'] = "controller/function";
```

To

```
$route['function'] = "controller/function";
```

User Guide URI Routing http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html

My Htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I already try it..
my Controller name is 'beranda'
but why it didnt work ?

Comment: I added my htacess works fine but do not know what type of operating system or localhost your using?

Comment: Should I overwrite that rules in my .htaccess file ?

Comment: I am using apache and windows

Comment: Here are some more htaccess for codeigniter https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter just find which one is best for your OS and Server And add it to main directory.

Comment: It didnt work dude, does routing can work with folder name inside it ?

Comment: Not much else can help with sorry